# I want to change a status message, show success if success then return to my first message

Tags: angularjs

I have my message as "Ready to Scan", if the scan success I want the background color to be green, and red if not then I need it to come back to the first message "Ready To Scan", mine now it stays on Scan Success and it doesn't return back to my original message.

```
    scanMsg = "Ready To Scan"
    if (data.status == "success") {
        scanMsg = "Scan Success";
    }else {
        scanMsg = "Failed";
        }
    }

    <div id="divScanMsg" class="cssTitleCenter cssFontS cssCurEdges pull-right" ng-class="'bg-green':vm.scanMsg==='Scan Success', 'bg-red': scanMsg === 'Failed'" style="height: 30vh; width: 50%; overflow-y:scroll; border-style:double; border-width:25px;">{{ vm.scanMsg }}</div>
```

Comment: more code. What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information to go on here -- show us your full directive and its template, not just a single out-of-context if/then block. (For starters you probably want to be putting `scanMsg` on scope if you want to use it in your directive.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless you reset the variable, its not gonna change! Try this using timeout.

```
function resetScanMsg(){
 $timeout(function(){
  $scope.scanMsg = 'Ready To Scan';
}, 2000);

$scope.someFn = function(){

 $scope.scanMsg = "Ready To Scan";

 if (data.status == "success") {
  $scope.scanMsg = "Scan Success";
  resetScanMsg();
 }else {
  $scope.scanMsg = "Failed";
  resetScanMsg();
 }

}
```

And for setting the background color, based on scanMsg use this in your html

```
<div ng-class="{'bg-red': scanMsg === 'Failed', 'bg-green': scanMsg === 'Scan Success'}"></div>
```

And define this in your css

```
.bg-red{
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-green{
  background-color: green;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, I will try it now.

Comment: This is definitely worked, I really appreciate that a lot sir.
Thank you sooooooo much. _ @Srijith

Comment: @MohdO If this worked for you, please accept the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @ SoEzPz and @Daniel Beck

Comment: @ Srijith, when I tried to change the style color it doesn't allow me. The message is working perfect but the styling is not working. I believe because I'm using class before ng-class.

Comment: @ Srijith, I added the html line at the end of the code just to show you what I got.